# AS2.0: I can't instantiate a class except at compile time? Could anyone explain what this means?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm sorry, this is probably a bit of a daft question, but I'm trying to write an Actionscript 2.0 class that handles loading XML data and then makes it accessible to the rest of the application.

However, this is the first time that I've written a class definition for anything that wasn't a MovieClip, and I'm running into a strange error. For instance here:

```
class Main extends SEBanner {

public function Main() {
    _root._quality = 'BEST';
    trace(_root._quality + ' SWF Quality Setting.');
    trace('Banner main object instantiated. Ready to run.')
    trace('Width of banner: ' + bannerWidth());
    trace('Height of banner: ' + bannerHeight());
    trace('Banner aspect ratio: ' + bannerAspectRatio());
    trace('----------------------------------------------');
}

public var externals:External = new External();

}
```

the last line, where I try to instantiate the External class (named so because it will handle externally-provided Flash variables as well as XML), is getting pegged by the compiler and it is giving me an error that translates to (I'm on a Japanese-language version of Flash) "A class instance variable can only be instantiated at compile time."

I'm confused because as far as I know, if the code is compiling, it IS compile time. And this code should have been OK, since the error came up when I compiled it.

Odd.

Thanks!

SS

Update: Here is the (stripped, to avoid showing any confidential info) External class for comparison:

```
import mx.xpath.XPathAPI;

class External {

private var _rawXML = new XML();
private var _xmlLocation:String = '';


public function External() {
    trace('Loading external information...');

    _rawXML.ignoreWhite = true;

    _rawXML.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
        if (success) {
            trace('XML data was successfully loaded.')
            initXML();
        } else {
            trace('There was an error loading the XML. Please check the XML file.');
        }
    }

    preLoadXML();
}



private function loadLocalXML():Void {
    getXML();
}


private function loadNetworkXML():Void {        
    getXML();
}

function getXML():Void {
    if ( _rawXML.load( _xmlLocation ) ) {
        trace('XML loading...');
    } else {
        trace('I\'m having difficulty finding the XML. You might want to check your data source.')
    }
}

function initXML():Void {
    _root._ary = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(this.rawXML, eventPath);
    _root._total = _ary.length;

    _root.siteLink = getXRedirect();
}

}
```

Comment: Odd indeed. You need to provide External class constructor and definition, perhaps it's a singleton class that has its own instantiation routine inside, and that one is throwing you the error. Or a static-typed class like Math, you can't instantiate a variable of Math class, and you've been hit with this. It also might be a translation error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The english error is: "A class's instance variables may only be initialized to compile-time constant expressions."

From my experience it goes something like this:

Think about class definitions as the "blueprint" on how each instance of that class should be created.

In your example, you define that each instance of "Main" should contain a definition of the class External and then you create an instance of that class and binds it to the variable externals [Main.externals]. The issue here is that that code [the definition of Main] is only run once [static, during startup when it loads all the definitions into memory] so each subsequent instance of Main would always be linked to the same instance of "External". Since you didn't mention in the code that you wanted this to be the case, you are provided with this error.

So, what you probably would like to do, is to inside the constructor of Main, create the instance of External --

```
public var externals:External;

public function Main() {
    _root._quality = 'BEST';
    externals = new External();
    trace('----------------------------------------------');
}
```

That way, each instance of Main would receive its own instance of external.
That at least solves your issue and would be more "correct" when it comes to how classes/instances work in coding languages.

If you, on the other hand, want ALL instances of Main to be linked to the same instance of External, you should just write

```
public static var externals:External = new External();

public function Main() {
    _root._quality = 'BEST';
    trace("external=" + externals);
    trace('----------------------------------------------');
}
```

Hope this makes sense, I realized that it was a bit hard to explain what I mean... :o

Comment: Testing some more, I realized I was partly wrong in my assumption since I thought it was linked to the fact that the class was a ReferenceObject which was not the case. The solution is still valid though, only the reasoning behind it is partially wrong.

Comment: The real issue is related to all the precompile-stages that actionscript goes through "under the hood". Probably linked to static constructor/class definitions and that the dynamic class that you tries to instantiate is not loaded into memory at that specific time since you told AS that that it was supposed to be a dynamic binding.

Comment: It's a non issue though since you either should tell the variable to be static (shared among all instances of Main) or that each instance of Main should have their own definition of it (create the instance of External inside Main's constructor)

Comment: Wow. This is an incredibly thorough and detailed answer. Thanks! I have one question though: my reasoning when I instantiated there was that I wanted the variable "externals" to be available throughout the Main class, not just inside the constructor. Actually, what I really want is for it to be available at all times to the entire project, but I'm not really sure how to do that, so I'm making instances in each class that needs to use it for now. Is there a way to do either of these?

Comment: Also, neither of these fixes actually works on my side. I'm getting a different error, though: "Unable to load class or interface 'External'". I'm sorry. I will update the problem above with my "External" class so the problem may be seen more clearly.

Comment: Oh, sorry I assumed you knew how classes works. Think of it this way, each time you create an instance you do it by running that class' constructor. So the constructor makes sure that you get a new instance of that class. Everything that "is not a local variable" [declared and defined inside a function] will live as long as there is a reference to it. Since the variable "externals" is "bound to the class", as long as that class lives [something else holds reference to it] it will be available. For more information, you should probably read some programming tutorial/book on AS/C#/Java.

Comment: The new error is most likely inside your fla-file (or whatever it is you uses to compile your project). You need to set it to include the folder where you have the "example.as"-file.

Comment: Here's a reference project, that works with Flash CS6:   https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=2733958C6465943C&resid=2733958C6465943C%21162&authkey=ADD1fp7JplF6TBA

Comment: OK. I think you've hit the problem. This is the first time I've used classes for anything other than MovieClip behavior, so I was unaware that I had to import the class into the Main.as before using it. I don't have a project namespace set up yet, just loose class files in the same folder as the .fla. I thought I could organize them into a project later - guess I was wrong! Also, you mentioned the incusion of the folder in the .fla file - I'm guessing that since the External.as file isn't linked to a library member (like all the others, via "Linkage"), it isn't being found by the .fla at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20931/discussion-between-stormshadow-and-daniel-messer)